# Trying to create a Tk() window + use while loop to print in shell

Tags: while-loop, tkinter

I'm new to Python. My code may be too simple, but I dont know why it wont work the way I want it to. Im trying to create a Tk() window before I print info into the shell but it will not create the window when I run it. I am using version 3.4. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root=Tk()
x=0
while x==0:print("hi");time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: All windowing systems require applications to process events while they are running. If you put the application main thread into a loop that does not process events you end up with an unresponsive application. Therefore the final command in tkinter apps is always to enter the mainloop which gets and dispatches system events. To do something while this is happening you raise your own events (using the `after` method) or event_generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally flawed. This is not how GUI development works. You should work through a tutorial, and try to understand the concept of an event loop.

Nevertheless, if your goal is to print to the console every half second forever, you would do it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_forever(root):
    print("hi")
    root.after(500, print_forever, root)

root = tk.Tk()
root.after_idle(print_once)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't want you to think I'm taking the lazy route. I've tried reading the tutorials. Unfortunately they are still very confusing to me. A good way for me to learn is from an example I can relate to, and I think the code I am asking for is simple enough to be shown quickly by a veteran.

Comment: @JohnW4: a veteran would never write a tkinter program with a while loop or print statements or a call to time.sleep, so what you're asking for is a bit of a non sequitur. Regardless, I'll show how an experienced tkinter programmer would infinitely print something every half second.